# Implement SCNSceneRendererDelegate on watchOS

Tags: watchkit, scenekit

On iOS, I can use `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` and implement `renderer(_:updateAtTime:)` in order to update my scene just before every frame is rendered. I set this up by doing this in my view controller:

```swift
(self.view as! SCNView).delegate = self
```

`SCNSceneRendererDelegate` is available on watchOS. However, on watchOS I don't have access to an `SCNView`, so I can't set its `delegate`. Is there any way, on watchOS, to get a callback right before each frame renders so that I can update my scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On watchOS you deal with `WKInterfaceSCNScene` (instead of `SCNView`) which also conforms to the `SCNSceneRenderer` protocol.

Comment: Thank you! I had to do one extra line to get it working. In addition to setting `self.scnInterface.delegate = self`, inside the `updateAtTime` callback, I had to set `renderer.isPlaying = true`. I couldn't find another place to get access to the renderer.